# How to prevent showing img tag in source code

Tags: php, html

how to prevent showing following code in source code.

**img tag code**

```
echo'<img src="jal.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />';
```

**source code**

```
<img  alt"Smiley face" src="http://www.myweb.com/jal.gif">
```

actually i don't want to show user image path.

thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with php...

Comment: Is this for some security reason?  You realize it's impossible to hide this from the user, right?  Browser tools, proxies, packet sniffers...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like that, commit the image to html file, with base64 encoding:

```
<img alt="Smiley face" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("jal.gif")); ?>" />
```

Comment: its works fine but problem is that its increasing the size of the page....as i have around 20 images in single page....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy and that is use a PHP page which actually load the image you want. For example, you can have this:

```
<img src="my_proxy.php?img=jal.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />
```

and then the `my_proxy.php` page will actually load the image you want using the `img` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to really hide the path, but you can use css to at least let the user go through some research to find your image's file path. Place your image inside a div and give that div a background image, like so

```
<div id="imgdiv"></div>
```

In css:

```
#imgdiv{
    background-image: url('http://www.myweb.com/jal.gif');
}
```

This is also nice because the user will not be able to drag your images away in the browser.

Comment: Sorry but in what way this solution "hide" the path apart the fact that a user has to view the css source?

Comment: As I said, it will definitely not hide the path - just make it a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The last solution from me :)

Code has security holes, if its a ok solution for you, i will edit my post and fix these security holes. Didn't tried the code. But in order to work, browser must support cookies for session, and its not perfect solution. User can get images via sniffer, or browser right click. It's impossible to perfect encrypt it. (you can implement javscript decrypt too, with ajax post)

i preassume `session_start()` included in pages.

**showimage.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Cotent-Type: image/jpeg");
    readfile($_SESSION["files"][$_REQUEST["id"]]);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $i=rand();
    $_SESSION["files"][$i]="cat.jpg";
    echo "<img src=\"showimage.php?id=".$id."\" />";
?>
```